# .htaccess direct access prevention technique preventing ajax request too

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, jquery

I am trying to prevent direct access to my include file but by doing so I am also unable to access file using the ajax call. Following is the code from my .htaccess file

```
<Files filename.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

Comment: Check this solution... (works for me!)

http://stackoverflow.com/a/23449295/2883501

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are made by the user's browser and hence will be coming from the user's IP address and not 127.0.0.1.

You can obfuscate your JavaScript but this isn't a 100% solution.
http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-online-javascript-obfuscator.htm